# how to update rows in database from sqlite database in android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I m new to android development.. i have an login and registration page through which i collect info of user like name email and mobile numbers after registration activity passes to finalsuccess were all info is displayed ...i want to update 3 mobile number that are already fetched from the database to the finalsuccess activity ... in that activity i want the already fetched numbers to be updated again in to database..plz help..thanks in advance..

**my table in SQliteDBhelperclass**

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "info.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "profile";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "userid";
    public static final String COLUMN_FULLNAME = "fullname";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String COLUMN_MOBILE = "mobile";
    public static final String COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE = "mobile2";
    public static final String COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE3 = "mobile3";
    public static final String COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE4 = "mobile4";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUERY =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLUMN_FULLNAME + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE3 + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE4 + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_MOBILE + " TEXT " + ")";
```

**my update method thats not working**

```
 public StringBuffer getData(){

        String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);

        StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();

        if (cursor!=null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {

                String mobile=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile2"));
                stringBuffer.append(" "+mobile+ "\n");


            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }
        return stringBuffer;
    }


    public void updatedata(String mob) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE,mob);


        sqLiteDatabase.update("TABLE_NAME",contentValues,"userid='5' and RELATIVE_MOBILE='mobile2'",null);


    }
```

**this is onclick update button**

```
enter code here
     sqLiteDBHelper.updatedata(editText.getText().toString());
            StringBuffer stringBuffer=sqLiteDBHelper.getData();
            tvshow.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            String op = tvshow.toString();



            Toast.makeText(LoginSuccessActivity.this, "Contacts updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a `ContentValues` object :

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Field1","Bob"); //These Fields should be your String values of actual column names
cv.put("Field2","19");
cv.put("Field2","Male");
```

Then use the update method, it should work now:

```
sqLiteDatabase.update(TableName, cv, "_id="+id, null);
```

Comment: no error but the already stored value is displayed into a edittext..not the updated one

Comment: Hey please remove Double quota   of the TABLE_NAME just pass TABLE_NAME otherwise you can pass like this "profile" sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"userid='5' and RELATIVE_MOBILE='mobile2'",null);

Comment: ERROR :- SQLiteException: no such column: RELATIVE_MOBILE (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE profile SET mobile2=? WHERE userid='5' and RELATIVE_MOBILE='mobile2'

Comment: Just replace your this  sqLiteDatabase.update("TABLE_NAME",contentValues,"userid='5' and RELATIVE_MOBILE='mobile2'",null);
 statement with  sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"userid='5' and RELATIVE_MOBILE='mobile2'",null);

Comment: Just replace your this  sqLiteDatabase.update("TABLE_NAME",contentValues,"userid='5' and RELATIVE_MOBILE='mobile2'",null);
 statement with  sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"userid= 5",null);

Comment: Try this hope so this will be working fine..                         SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
   
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE,mob);
   
        // updating row  
        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, COLUMN_ID + " = 5");

Comment: these is displaying two mob nos.now ..the actual one that i was updating and the already one which is in database ..and storing only the old one only

Comment: you can also put where condition inside update statement for getting proper output...according to your business logic.

Comment: if i put a where condition inside  again it is errored ...with egalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  2 arguments were provided

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 db.update("Put your table name here", contentValues, "put your unique column name" + "='" + id + "'", null);
```

in you case syntax is :

```
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put("COLUMN_MOBILE","Bob");
  db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, COLUMN_ID + "='" + id + "'", null);
```

in which id is your passed parameter value.

Comment: NumberFormatException: For input string: "8000099999" error in dis

Comment: wat id "bob" after COLUMN_MOBILE??

Comment: id is your column_id like row number is 5 then you have to pass 5 over there like:int id =5;    db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, COLUMN_ID + "='" + id + "'", null);

Comment: its giving error :--SQLiteException: no such column: COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE (code 1):

Comment: wat should be putted into public void update(String s)instead of String s or (String mobile)?

Comment: update methods of helper class----

    public void updatedata(String s) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("COLUMN_RELATIVE_MOBILE","Bob");
        //sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, COLUMN_ID + "='" + 5 + "'", null);
        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,"userid= 5",null);

    }

Comment: onclick update button......  sqLiteDBHelper.updatedata(editText.getText().toString());
                StringBuffer stringBuffer=sqLiteDBHelper.getData();
                tvshow.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
                String op = tvshow.toString();

                Log.d("update query: "+op,"in LoginActivity");

                Toast.makeText(LoginSuccessActivity.this, "Contacts updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: edit this line like : sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, COLUMN_ID + "='1' ", null);

Comment: These works but it deosnt store the mobile number into db....it only displays in the edittext..below

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with the code below

sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"userid='5' and RELATIVE_MOBILE='mobile2'",null);